# Полезно ли использовать списки?

Tags: html, html5, seo

Разбираюсь в том когда стоит использовать **спиcoк ul**, а когда нет...
Когда речь идёт о главном меню или галереи, то необходимость использования списков достаточно очевидна. **Но как стоит поступать в менее очевидных ситуациях?** 
Например, в верхней правой части страниц сайтов часто размещают панель с кнопкой "Вход" и интерфейсом для поиска. 
С одной стороны - это вроде бы список, перечисляющий дополнительные возможности пользователя. А с другой стороны, на них можно смотреть, как на два разных элемента различной структуры и верстать без списков.
**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё таки правильнее делать?** 
Просто если задуматься, то всегда на страницы можно найти много списков, но сам синтаксис ul/li достаточно грамосткий, и как мне кажется, несколько захламляет код, если пользоваться ими слишком часто...

Answer (score 1):

Если у меня возникает вопрос каким образом расположить элементы, списком, блоками или другими вариантами, я стараюсь оценить в первую очередь, что я буду делать с ними дальше. То есть, какие трудности могут возникнуть в будущем. В действительности для SEO не будет лишним использование списков, машины привыкли к таком написанию, как минимум для меню и крошек списки лучше, для других пунктов не хуже. А вот отдельные элементы, захломление кода для чтения, с другой стороны он быстрее верстается, а с аккуратными руками и быстро обслуживается.

Answer (score 0):

да, использовать список можешь сколько хочешь и речь не идет о полезности,а о удобстве при работе с ними, но все таки я, например, использую только для меню,хлебных крошек, каких нибудь повторяющихся блоков, текстовые списки конечно же, хотя так же можно это все сделать с помощью div'ов, но зачем заморачиваться, если есть для этого отведенный ul. кнопки и поисковые формы лучше, как по мне, выносить отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Списки полезно использовать когда у тебя много структуированных однотипных данных вместе. Те же меню, всплывающие окошки и так далее. Они все очень удобно сгрупированны и обратаваются легко с помощью встроенных css свойств. Хотя всё ещё зависит от вида верстки. Если будешь делать резиновую вёрстку, то стоит задуматься как она у тебя будет выглядеть. Иногда проще блоки сделать, так как их удобней перемещать по странице.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, необходимо для начала смотреть, где зачастую их используют другие - условно, изучить качественные сайты, например - и делать аналогичные решения самостоятельно. а с опытом придет и понимание, где они нужны, а где нет.
ибо вопрос больше не о том, как правильнее, а о том, где их удобнее использовать с точки зрения будущей стилизации под нужды интерфейса. а чтобы это понять, надо попробовать одну и ту же задачу решить через `ul>li`, потом `span`, потом `div`... и сделать вывод для себя.
касательно всех тривиальных задач - меню навигации и прочее - всё уже придумано до нас, велосипед изобретать нет необходимости)

п.с. возможно вопрос СЕО может ответить более чётко, но тут не подскажу